# reccuring events got displayed twicely on page(shows both edited reccuring event and event which was shown before editing)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar

here am trying to fetch some events(including reccurring)from SP calendar list,here am able to get hese dailly reccurring events,here am getting events and when editing any reccuring event then it shows this same event means it shows the event same as un-edited and also shows this edited event and this is happening only after first editing,i dont understand why it does this?My code is as below

```
 function Retrieve() {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL
        var context = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostWebUrl);
        var web = context.get_web(); //Get the Site 
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(ListName); //Get the List based upon the Title
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
        var items = list.getItems(query);
        var fields = list.get_fields();
        ctx.load(items);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            RetrieveEvents(items);
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    }

    function RetrieveEvents(items) {
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        var recordCount = 0;
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
            EventDte = currentListItem.get_item('EventDate');
            RecurrenceEvent = currentListItem.get_item("fAllDayEvent");

            var eDate = EventDte;
            var cDate = new Date();

            var d1 = eDate.split("/");
            var d2 = cDate.split("/");

            var dateOfEvent = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1]) - 1, d1[0]); 
            var todaysDate = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1]) - 1, d2[0]);

            if (dateOfEvent >= todaysDate) {
                recordCount++;
                var eventDate = currentListItem.get_item('EventDate');
                var EventId = currentListItem.get_item('ID'); //"Id";
                var LocationField = currentListItem.get_item('Location'); //"Location";    
                var RecurrenceField = currentListItem.get_item('fRecurrence'); //"fRecurrence";      
                var EndDateField = currentListItem.get_item('EndDate'); //"EndDate";     
                var EventTypeField = currentListItem.get_item('EventType'); //"EventType";     
                var SeriesIdField = currentListItem.get_item('MasterSeriesItemID'); //"MasterSeriesItemID";
                var recurrenceData = currentListItem.get_item("RecurrenceData");
                var TitleField = currentListItem.get_item('Title'); //"Title";     

                var a = moment(DateInList, 'YYYY M D');
                var b = moment(EndDateField, 'YYYY M D');
                var diffDays = b.diff(a, 'days');

                if (RecurrenceField === true && EventTypeField != 3) {
                    for (var dateDifference = 0; dateDifference <= diffDays; dateDifference++) {
                        var defaultdte = new Date(eventDate);
                        defaultdte.setDate(defaultdte.getDate() + dateDifference);
                        if (Rorcounter < ItemLimit) {
                            if (EventTypeField === 4) {
                                eventUrl = EventId + ".1." + SeriesIdField;
                                listItemURL = hostWebUrl + '/Lists/' + Title + '/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + eventUrl;
                            }
                            if (EventTypeField === 1) {
                                listItemURL = hostWebUrl + '/Lists/' + Title + '/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + EventId + '.0.' + dateInURL;
                            }
                            innerHtml += "<div'>"
                            innerHtml += "<a href=" + listItemURL + ">" + EndDateField+"</a>"
                            innerHtml += " <p>" + defaultdte + "</p>"
                            innerHtml += "</div>"
                            Rorcounter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (Rorcounter < ItemLimit) {
                        listItemURL = hostWebUrl + '/Lists/' + Title + '/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + EventId;
                        innerHtml += "<div>"                            
                        innerHtml += "<a href=" + listItemURL + ">" + TitleField +  "</a>"
                        innerHtml += " <p class='des'>" + eventDate + "</p>"
                        innerHtml += "</div>"
                        Rorcounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            innerHtml += "</div>";
        }
        if (recordCount <= 0) {
            innerHtml += "<p>no Item Found.</p><p></p>"
        }
        $(".events").html(innerHtml);
    }
```

the snapp will make better clarification
[image]

how can i avoid this kind of duplication of record?